# How to change a string into an object

Tags: java

I've  been trying to figure out how to get the String bookWanted, and customerName to bookWritten and buyer name, but i can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I've tried changing the string to a book after it was made but I can't do that.

```
    static List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

    public void buyBook(Book bookWritten, Person buyerName) {
        System.out.println("Write your name: ");

        String bookWanted = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Write the book you want: ");    

        String customerName = scanner.nextLine();

        for(int b = 0; b<books.size(); b++) {
            if(books.get(b).equals(bookWritten)) {
                bookWritten.setBuyer(buyerName);
            }
        }       
        for(int b = 0; b<people.size(); b++) {
            if(people.get(b).equals(buyerName)) {
                buyerName.addBooksBought(bookWritten);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println("Write your name: ");

        String bookWanted = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Write the book you want: ");    

        String customerName = scanner.nextLine();` is ass about face

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know

```
if(books.get(b).equals(bookWritten)) {
```

and

```
if(people.get(b).equals(buyerName)) {
```

They doing equals on the `Book` and `Person` object, which by default performs `return (this == obj)`, i.e.: it returns true only they are the same object (if you haven't overridden the `equals` in `Book` or `Person`)

And you need to take care that you did nothing about the `bookWanted` and `customerName` the user typed.